# Map two Nokogiri objects

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

A quick question:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>foo</th>
    <td><p>bar</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  details  = doc.css('table > tr > th')
  details2 = doc.css('table > tr > td > p')

  details  = details.map { |n| { name: n.text }}
  details2 = details2.map { |n| { value: n.text }}
```

How can I merge those Nokogiri objects in one `map` statement?

Output:

```
{:name=>"abc"}
{:name=>"ghj"}
{:name=>"lmn"}
{:value=>"123"}
{:value=>"456"}
{:value=>"789"}
```

I need something like this:

```
{:name=>"abc", :value=>"123"}
```

I tried something like this:

```
details = details.map { |n| { name: n.text, value: n.css('table > tr > td > p').map { |x| {value: x} }}}
details = details.map { |n| {name: n.text, value: n.css('table > tr > td').attr('p').to_s} }
```

Comment: Welome to Stack Overflow. You need to supply a minimal example of the HTML showing what you're talking about. Asking us to cobble something up only slows us, and increases the chance of you getting something that won't work for your use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
details  = doc.css('table > tr > th')
details2 = doc.css('table > tr > td > p')

details.map!.with_index { |d, i| {name: d.text, value: details2[i].text } }
```

`details` will look like `[{name: 'asd', value: '123'}, {name: 'qwe', value: '234'}]`

Comment: Good morning, Thanks everyone for helping to get this question done as soon as possible. But I can only accept one answer, and this was the closest to solve my problem. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

CSS supports multiple selectors, and Nokogiri's use of CSS respects that:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>foo</th>
        <td><p>bar</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

text = doc.search('table tr th, table tr td p').map(&:text)
text # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Or a little more cleanly:

```
rows = doc.search('table tr')
text = rows.search('th, td p').map(&:text)
text # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Note that multiple selectors work sequentially. In other words, they find the first selector then the second, etc., so if you need to know the actual order things occurred in the document you'll have to use individual searches or look at the actual nodes to determine their place in the DOM.

Also note I'm using the generic `search` not the more specific `css`. Nokogiri is smart enough to do the right thing most of the time when it comes to using CSS or XPath, so it's more convenient to use `search` or `at`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, the arrays contain objects in the valid/same order:

```
details.zip(details2).map { |e| e.inject &:merge }
```